# Section sign is being replaced by &#167

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, and am having trouble removing special symbols like the Section Sign `§`

```
var str = '§7The quick brown fox jumps over §3the lazy dog';
var ans = str.replace(/§/g, "");
```

When I load the page, it shows:

```
var ans = str.replace(/&#167/g, "");
```

The string is left the same when the code is run.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nd0k3f16/

Comment: Yep works for me too

Comment: If something is converting characters in your javascript to HTML entities, something else is going on.